# iCloud slideshow - shuffle photos

Tags: icloud

I am creating a slideshow for an event that individuals are adding to a shared album on iCloud. I would like to shuffle the photos. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on what device you are viewing the photos.

In case of iPhone:

To view slides in random order (shuffle) turn the shuffle on.

[image: shuffle]